# How to make transition to work whan I remove a class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem with my CSS3, HTML5, jQuery menu.
It is a simple menu that has transformX(-100%) and transformX(0%) depending on is active class added.For adding a class everything goes smooth, but when I remove the class it just disappears,no transition there. How to make transition to work when a class is removed?
Here is my code, its simple(at least I hope so :)

HTML

```
    <nav class="menu" role="navigation"> 
        <ul class="menu-items-list">
            <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
.menu {
            position: absolute;
            display: block;

            overflow: hidden;
            transform: translateY(-100%);
            transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.92,.7,.64,1);
        }
        .menu-active {
            min-height: 200px;
            min-width: 200px;
            max-height: 500px;
            max-width: 500px;
            z-index: 6;
            transform: translateY(0%);
            transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(.92,.7,.64,1);
        }
```

jQuery

```
function meni(selektor, arclass) {
    selektor.toggleClass(arclass);
    return false;
}
 var menu = $('#menu-icon'),
     mmenu = $('.menu'),
     menuactive = 'menu-active';

 menu.on('click', function(){
     meni( mmenu, menuactive);
 });
```

Comment: where is `#menu-icon` element?

Comment: You need to post a working code snippet, as the above won't work as is

Comment: codepen for this:
http://codepen.io/stelarossa/pen/wgbOrp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the above won't work as is, I changed targeted element to the `ul`

I also changed `menu.on('click', function()` to `mmenu.on('click', function()`, one `m` was missing in the word `menu`, and that was all to make it work.

I made my answer a wiki as it appears to be a typo, and am considering voting to close it as such

```js
function meni(selektor, arclass) {
  selektor.toggleClass(arclass);
  return false;
}
var menu = $('#menu-icon'),
  mmenu = $('.menu'),
  menuactive = 'menu-active';

mmenu.on('click', function() {
  meni(mmenu, menuactive);
});
```

```css
.menu ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translateY(-250%);
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.92, .7, .64, 1);
}

.menu-active ul {
  /*min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;*/
  max-height: 500px;
  max-width: 500px;
  z-index: 6;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(.92, .7, .64, 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="menu" role="navigation">
  Click here
  <ul class="menu-items-list">
    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks,thats it!How to mark your anser as appropriate solution?